# GLUT glutCloseFunc callback not being called

Tags: windows, opengl, glut

I am using GLUT for a CUDA project at university and all is going well with it.

I have set up GLUT with a number of callbacks like so:

```
glutKeyboardFunc( on_key );
glutDisplayFunc( on_draw );
glutMouseFunc(on_mouse);
glutMotionFunc( on_motion );
glutIdleFunc( on_idle );
glutCloseFunc( on_exit );
glutReshapeFunc( on_reshape );
```

Only problem is that on_exit is never called but all the others are and there is no difference between the functions I have set up.

I know that my exit code works fine as I call it from on_key when the ESC key is down.

Does anyone know why this might not be working? Do I need to set some flags or some such to dictate its behavior?

Comment: Are you including GL/glut.h or GL/freeglut.h? On my machine, freeglut.h includes freeglut_ext.h which defines glutCloseFunc. But your code shouldn't even compile if you don't include freeglut_ext.h... Perhaps you're linking incorrectly?